# Show/hiding a alert based on clicking on a button in Vuejs

Tags: html, css, vue.js, emit

I have an alert (snackbar) in my registration component that I want to show only when property `activeSection` is equal to `'step-1'`.
The tricky part is I cannot directly call snackbar component into my registration component directly. I can only display the snackbar by emitting properties from registration to snackbar component.

I have written a piece of code that shows the snackbar when page loads, but when I change the `activeSection` property by clicking on a button the snackbar doesn't disappear eventhough I want it to disappear, what's the best way to do it?

This is the relevant parts from registration.js:

```
data: function () {
    return {
      activeSection: "step-1"
.
.
mounted(){
    if (this.activeSection === 'step-1') {
      EventBus.$emit("add-snack", {
        message: "Hello World",
        type: "success"
      });
    }
```

This is the relevant part from snackbar.html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-300" @click.prevent="activeSection='step-2'">
            CONTINUE
          </button>
```

**Please note that I want to watch if `activeSection` changes and if it did then I want my code to stop emitting the snackbar properties.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJS Showing and Hiding Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481357/vuejs-showing-and-hiding-messages)

Comment: `@click.prevent="removeSnack", ... methods: removeSnack() { EventBus.$emit('remove-snack') ) ... @remove-snack="appear=false"  <div v-if="appear"></div>`.