# Laravel 5.6 Flash Messages has to close automaticly

Tags: laravel, flash-message

It's the first time I develop something and so the first time with laravel.
Now I have made flash_error message and I want that those are closing after 3 seconds. Have no idea of how you do that.

This is the way I write then in my Controllers:

```
return redirect('/admin/settings')->with('flash_message_error', 'Incorrect Current Password!');
```

And this is the way I add then in my blade.php page:

```
@if(Session::has('flash_message_error'))
    <div class="alert alert-error alert-block">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button> 
        <strong>{!! session('flash_message_error') !!}</strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

Now the question how do I get then closed automaticlly and what I have to do for it

Comment: welcome to so, If you want to do it via vuejs, then this might help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481357/vuejs-showing-and-hiding-messages

Answer (score 2):

Use Jquery like

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       $("div.alert").remove();
    }, 3000 ); // 3 secs

});
```

Comment: did your problem got fixed? @buro71